# Get Meta_Value from WP database

Tags: php, jquery, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to do a database query that will return the meta_value of a particular row in the postmeta table based on the post ID.  Then pass the variable as an integer to a jQuery variable.  Here's what my code looks like:

```
function getListings() {
  var value3 = jQuery("#input_1_3").val();
  if (value3 === 'something')  {
    value3 = <?php echo $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT meta_value 
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id = 11" ); 
    ?>;
  }
}
```

Right now it's returning a weird series of numbers and a ";"...The result I need should be an integer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm sure it's something obvious, but don't know what.

UPDATED:

Here is a screenshot of one of the tables I'm trying to get a meta_value from.  The value I want to retrieve is "5".

[image: PostMeta]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using the built-in WP function [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/):

NOTE: You need a "key" when doing this - what value are you hoping to return? You're going to get multiple values unless you define a key:

```
function getListings() {
  var value3 = jQuery("#input_1_3").val();
  if (value3 === 'something')  {
    value3 = <?php echo get_post_meta(11, 'my_key', TRUE) ?>; 
  }
}
```

**Based on your edits**, it looks like the key is `pack_listings`, so the code would be as follows:

```
function getListings() {
    var value3 = jQuery("#input_1_3").val();
    if (value3 === 'something')  {
      value3 = <?php echo get_post_meta(11, 'pack_listings', TRUE) ?>; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The value I'm hoping to get is just an integer, like 5.  It's the only meta_value associated with that post.  So I'm curious what the "key" would be.

Comment: @Christian - show me how you wrote the meta value, and I'll show you how you can retrieve it.

Comment: Sure, I just updated my original question with a screenshot of the table and value I'm trying to retrieve

Comment: Ok, I did a little more research and it works.  I just had to remove the "wp_" from "wp_get_post_meta..."

Answer (score 0):

Your code for value3 shoukd be this

```
    function getListings() {
     var value3 = jQuery("#input_1_3").val();
    if (value3 === 'something')  {
    Value3=<?php echo get_post_meta(11,'pack_listings', true); ?>
      }
    }
```